# How JVM Clustering for load balancing.

Tags: java, memory, jvm, cluster-computing

Default JVM uses maximum 1.5 GB RAM/JVM Java application.
But my Server have 8 GB. Application still need more RAM. how to start cluster of JVM single unit server.

if in case memory increase single JVM garbage collector and other JVM demon goes slow down...
what is solution for this.. is right thing JVM clusters???

Application work high configuration. when request start JVM slow down and memory usage 95% to 99%

My server configuration. Linux
4 Core Multi Processors
8 GB RAM
no issue for HDD space.

Any Solution for this problem??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into memory grids like:

- Oracle Coherence: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/coherence/overview/index.html
- GridGain: http://www.gridgain.com/
- Terracotta: http://terracotta.org/

We use Coherence to run 3 JVMs on 1 machine, each process is using 1 Gb of the RAM.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of solutions.

- Use a larger heap size (possibly 64-bit JVM)
- Use less heap and more off heap memory. Off heap memory can scale into the TB.
- Split the JVM into multiple processes.  This is easier for some applications than others. I tend to avoid this as my applications can't be split easily.

Comment: Sorry developing 64bit Linux OS version is costly for us.. is there any other way??

Comment: If you have to use a 32-bit JNI library, you can run this, and only this in a seperate JVM. The rest of the application you run in 64-bit.